# Breakpoint In Script Task (Control Flow Task) Even if I set Run64BitRuntime = False

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, ssis, ssis-2012

I'm facing strange issue in my Visual Studio SSIS. I'm not able to debug the code in Script Task (Control Flow Task). It is opening the new window and after few seconds it is closing back. It doesn't hit the break point. I did the below workarounds, but nothing worked.

- I set `Run64BitRuntime = False` - No Luck
- I ran the VS as administrator - No Luck.

[image]

How can I get rid of this issue?

Comment: Can we please see your script? Do you have any $$ sign infront of hardcode values eg?

Answer (score 0):

I've faced that before and what I did was:

1. Insert a break point PreExecution and PostExecution in the
   Sequence Container that holds the Script task.
2. Insert a break point in the Script Task code.
3. Close the VS and open it again.
4. Run the SSIS.